# best way to handle events and notifications from multiple sources to a main form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I have a vb.net application in which there is a main form. There are around 10 classes each having their own functionalities like tcpactions, fileactions, serialport actions etc. The user interacts with the main form and does certain actions which will invoke the methods in these classes. Now I have a notifications textarea in the mainform and i want to show the current action being performed in those classes and their results in the notifications area.

for example when a user clicks a "Start Process" Button in the form i invoke the method "launchprocess" in a class "ProcessActions". Now this method tries to launch about 7 different process and after launching it sends notification such as "process 1 launched" or if it fails it sends notifications such as "process 1 launch failed".

I currently use event handlers and use them to show notifications but with the amount of events i have to handle it is getting cumbersome and i might have to add even more classes in the future. So is there a better way of handling notifications from other classes.

Comment: @Hans your comment doesn't seem very accurate. I can think of many examples where the program is telling the user what it's doing. ie: deleting files shows a graphic of a file going to the recycle bin and displays the name of the file being currently deleted. When it's finished it goes away. For any program that a user is interacting with there has to be someway for them to know that it's completed the current process.  Otherwise they're left sitting there trying to decide if the program worked, if it errored out, or if it's still processing.

Comment: @HansPassant pls dont come to the conclusion that its useless code without even knowing what app im trying to build. (im sick of this know-all attitude) i am making an application to test an embedded device in which the user clicks one single button after filling certain data and the app does all sorts of port testing and i want to give the user the current status of the test. I dont think this would be "useless code"

Comment: Don't hesitate to put relevant details in your question, helps people give you a better answer.  Having them guess at it does produce annoyance on either end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a common custom event handler in all of the classes that the main form can respond to.  First define a new EventArgs class to handle the notifications you're sending back:

```
Public NotInheritable Class NtfyEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Private _Action As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Action As String
        Get
            Return _Action
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal action As String)
        _Action = action
    End Sub
End Class
```

Next define a base class to raise the notifications:

```
Public Class Base
    Public Event Ntfy(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NtfyEventArgs)

    Protected Sub RaiseNtfy(ByVal action As String)
        RaiseEvent Ntfy(Me, New NtfyEventArgs(action))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Have each of your other classes inherit from the base class.  Then it becomes quite easy to send a notification:

```
Public Class ProcessActions
    Inherits Base

    Public Sub LaunchProcess
        'Do stuff
        RaiseNtfy("Process 1 launched")

        'Do more stuff
        RaiseNtfy("Process 2 launched")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Finally in your main form, listen for any events raised by the child classes

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents process As New ProcessActions
    Private WithEvents file As New FileActions

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Add Event handlers
        AddHandler process.Ntfy, AddressOf HandleNtfy
        AddHandler file.Ntfy, AddressOf HandleNtfy
    End Sub

    'One procedure to handle all the incoming notifications
    Private Sub HandleNtfy(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as NtfyEventArgs) 
        lblNtfy.Text = e.Action

        'If need to take different actions based on the class sending notification
        If TypeOf(Sender) Is ProcessActions Then
            'Specific code for ProcessActions
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: +1: This is a pattern I use in most of my winforms based tools. I've taken it a step further by abstracting it all out into a library so that my winforms actually inherit my own forms base class that contains the event definitions, a background worker process instance, etc.